# Starting nginx bounces "unknown directive brotli" error

Tags: nginx, ubuntu-22.04, brotli

Goal: I am trying to make a Ubuntu 22.04 server available online.

Approach: I have a fresh VM with Ubuntu, Plesk, docker, docker-compose, papermerge and nginx installed on it.

Problem: When I try to start nginx, this error is prompted:

```
nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "brotli" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/brotli.conf:1
```

brotli.conf looks like this:

```
brotli on;
brotli_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
```

What would you suggest I do to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

NGINX open source does not have compiled brotli module. You need to compile the NGINX brotli module from source.

Answer (score 0):

Since version 18.0.33 Plesk comes with Nginx and Brotli enabled by default. Make sure it is turned on by running (as root) "plesk bin nginx -e brotli". More details that can help: [Plesk KB article on Brotli with Nginx](https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/12387812757143). If you are using Nginx in a Docker container, then indeed it may need be a specially compiled version with Brotli.